# Variable and operator seem to be ignored in assignment. What can make this happen?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, segmentation-fault

I am debugging an android app and I see that stepping over in eclipse debug view:

```
    int bottom, right;
    bottom = 800;
    right = 480;
    float h ,v;
    h = right/86.0f;
    v = bottom/116.0f;
```

The values on the debug view says that h = 86.0 and v = 116.0

So it's the debugger showing the right values? What can make that happen?

hint 1: if I change the literal 86.0f for, say 54.0f, then h = 54.0 and the same for v 
hint 2: these values are right in debug view when the app runs fine, but no when it does not (exception caught, app finishes and SEGV_MAPERR ) which appears to happen long after this code, and affected by the use of this incorrect values of h and v.

Comment: Basic sanity: Is the source code in sync with the running app? Before which line of code are you breaking?

Comment: Please how can I know if its out of sync? The breakpoint is at a line before the code shown. It's another simple assignment.

Comment: I don't suppose there's some later bit of code where you write `h = right/h` and `v = bottom/v`? :-P

Comment: If you don't trust your debugger, you can always add println statements to do a sanity check.

Comment: lol @ruakh there is no inversion afterwards. Log.d shows the same thing in LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure but it seems that i faced a Dalvik limitation. Playing a bit with the code, a VerifyError appeared, which lead me to [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/ISanO6DPet4). After reducing the number of variables in my larger methods and splitting them the problem seems to be gone.